# Ftplib download zip file attempts fail ([Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\kbrab\\Desktop\\2019\\test.zip)

Tags: python, ftp, ftplib

I have been trying to set up an automated python script to download files from a remote FTP server to a local machine. I was able to establish a connection, navigate to the directory however when attempting to download the specific zip file I get an error.

[Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\Users\kbrab\Desktop\2019\test.zip'

I have tried Running IDLE as an administrator, I have also checked to make sure the local path directory is created and correct. Checking Other similar posts  that seemed to be the issue. The FTP server is TLS/SSL Implicit encryption, the python file is being run on a windows VM.

```py
def checkKindred():
    time = a_day_in_previous_month()
    print(time)
    lines = []
    ftp_client.cwd('/kindred/')
    print("Current directory: " + ftp_client.pwd())
    ftp_client.retrlines('NLST',lines.append)
    nameCh = ("Attrition_"+str(time))
    for line in lines:
        if nameCh == line[:17]:
            print("found match")
            print(line)
            fileName = line
            unpackKindred(fileName,time)

def unpackKindred(name,time):
    local_path = "C:\\Users\\kbrab\\Desktop"
    local_path = os.path.join(local_path, str(time)[:4],"Attrition_2019-04-30.zip")
    if not os.path.exists(local_path):
        os.makedirs(local_path)
    try:
        filenames = ftp_client.nlst()
        ftp_client.retrbinary('RETR '+name, open(local_path, 'wb').write)      
    except Exception as e:
        print('Failed to download from ftp: '+ str(e))
```

The code is now working through martin's insight, adding corrected code below:

```py
def unpackKindred(name,time):
    local_path = "C:\\Users\\kbrab\\Desktop"
    local_path = os.path.join(local_path, str(time)[:4])
    if not os.path.exists(local_path):
        os.makedirs(local_path)
    filename = os.path.join(local_path, name)
    file = open(filename, "wb")
    ftp_client.retrbinary("retr " + name, file.write)
```

Comment: So what throws the exception? `open` or `retrbinary`? Show us exception callstack.

Comment: Also how can the file path be `C:\Users\kbrab\Desktop\2019\test.zip` if you do `local_path = os.path.join(local_path, str(time)[:4],"Attrition_2019-04-30.zip")`?

Comment: That callstack does not really help us answering my question. Separate the `open` and `retrbinary` calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This creates a *folder* `C:\Users\kbrab\Desktop\2019\test.zip`:

```
if not os.path.exists(local_path):
    os.makedirs(local_path)
```

And this tries to treat the folder as if it were a file:

```
ftp_client.retrbinary('RETR '+name, open(local_path, 'wb').write)
```

Answer (score -1):

Check the permissions of the folder. Set it so everyone has full control.